# how to make a call in android

Tags: android, call

I am trying to make a call from my Application on a click of a image 
and it is here by done like this  But it is Giving me Exception ActivityNotFoundException
 How Should i handle this .. ?

```
    Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if("N/A".equals(Number)){
                            MsgBox(ctx,"Could not call because there is no number ");
                        }
                        else{
                            fnCallMobile("+91"+Number);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

And  my fnCallMobile function is :

```
public void fnCallMobile(String PhoneNo){
        ConfirmMsgBox(this,"Are you sure you want to call number "+PhoneNo,PhoneNo);
    }
    public void ConfirmMsgBox(Context ctx,String msg,final String sPhoneNo){
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Emkay Eagle");
        dialog.setMessage(msg);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                fnCall(sPhoneNo);
            }

        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                return;
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alert.show();
        return;
    }
```

And lastly my fnCall Function

```
public void fnCall(String PhoneNo){
        try{
            Intent callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("Tel:"+PhoneNo));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex){
            sResponse=ex.toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem ?your code seems fine if you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 in your manifest

Comment: @Akki It gives me Activity Not Found Exception Near
Intent in my try catch

Comment: Try to change the protocol to `"tel"` (in lowercase). Not sure, but maybe case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Change 

`callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("Tel:"+PhoneNo));` 

 to 

`callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+PhoneNo));`
```

Comment: I have already declared the permission
When it come to intent it gives exception ActivitynotFoundException ?

Comment: whats  the difference between Tel and tel..?

Comment: Well started working for mr though Thnaks
But wats the difference between Tel and tel.?

Comment: Java is a case sensitive language.

Comment: Thanks Chirag  you don great job

Answer (score 0):

Use scheme as tel: instead of Tel:

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+PhoneNo));
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the URI, you should use `tel:` instead of.`Tel:` as protocols are case-sensitive. Note that this is suggested by your error, which is telling you your URI is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = "tel:" + number;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```